# Grayscale Level Change - C#

Tags: c#, image, formula, grayscale

Im trying to convert grayscale bitmap pixels to lower gray levels, but I dont know the name of the formula that is used for calculating it, nor I know how it works - Right now I have some shady code that doesnt seem to always work(almost never) correctly.

The images vary in levels of gray (from 2 to 256), and I need it a formula to be able to get down-leveled easily(and having a reverse formula for the pixel data to still be between 0 and 255).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the current code:

```
        int xIndex = 0, yIndex = 0;
        if (grayLevelPreview <= 0) return;//error- only one shade, dividing by zero calculation ahead - stop
        if (grayLevelPreview > grayLevel) grayLevelPreview = grayLevel;
        int levels = grayLevel / grayLevelPreview;
        for (int i = 0; i < dataListPreview.Count; i++)//assign each pixel data to bitmap coordinates
        {
            dataListPreview[i] /= levels;
            int grayLeveler = dataListPreview[i] * levels;

            bm.SetPixel(xIndex, yIndex, Color.FromArgb(1, grayLeveler, grayLeveler, grayLeveler));
            xIndex++;
            if (i % imgWidth == 0 && i != 0)
            {
                yIndex++;
            }
            if (xIndex == imgWidth)
            {
                xIndex = 0;
            }
        }
```

Comment: You want to make the image darker? Using a ColorMatrix is an easier (and faster) way.

Comment: I need it to have less color depth - and I need not use libraries

Comment: a) ColorMatrix is part of .NET GDI b) multiplying each channel by a float < 1f will make it darker; but it will also lose some information. The move back dividing by that number would recovers as well as possible. c) clor depth is a matter of the file format and can't be achieve within one format. d) What do you know abourt the input data?

Comment: color depth is unrelated to this... that's related to bit per pixel storage of the image. If this is an 8bpp image, all you need to do is edit the palette.

Comment: Seems the way I did it in the start of the loop(first 2 lines of it) is more or less working, but the maximum value of it is not 255, but instead I see values like 155 - not sure where that came from though, was expecting at least to have a maximum value of 127 instead